# Expose a ViewModel event for binding to a custom DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to expose a public event from my ViewModel is such a way as to allow it to be bound to a custom DependencyProperty in my View?

My application is written in C# using the .NET 4.5 framework.  It has a MVVM architecture with no code-behind in the view and custom DependencyProperty classes to bind WPF-specific behvaiours of the View to properties exposed by the ViewModel.

There is a set of properties that I would like the ViewModel to be able to expose that represent events to which the View needs to respond.  For example, when a top level ViewModel object is about to be Disposed I would like the WPF View implementation to respond by closing the corresponding Window.  This could occur when a configuration process has displayed a Dialog Window, the user has enetered and confirmed the information and the ViewModel has passed it to the Model and is no longer required.

**I am aware that there are many questions that are specific to solving the 'show dialog from ViewModel' question; this is not one of them and I have a solution to that one.**

I've read through the MSDN documentation for DependencyProperties and can't find anything specific to binding to event properties.

What I would like to achieve is something similar to the code below.  This code builds, but results in a typical `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'RequestCloseEvent' property not found` error when the MainWindow is shown.

**I am aware that there are many questions that go along the lines of 'please help me debug my System.Windows.Data Error: 40 issue'; this is (probably) not one of these either.**  (But I'd be happy if that's all it really is.)

Source for the custom DependencyProperty in WindowBindableProperties.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfEventBinding
{
    public static class WindowBindableProperties
    {
        #region ViewModelTerminatingEventProperty

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the ViewModelTerminatingEvent custom DependencyProperty.
        /// </summary>
        private static DependencyProperty _viewModelTerminatingEventProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        (
            "ViewModelTerminatingEvent",
            typeof(ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler),
            typeof(WindowBindableProperties),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, ViewModelTerminatingEventPropertyChanged)
        );

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the ViewModelTerminatingEvent dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static DependencyProperty ViewModelTerminatingEventProperty
        { get { return _viewModelTerminatingEventProperty; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the attached ViewModelTerminatingEvent dependecy property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dependencyObject">The window attached to the WindowViewModel.</param>
        /// <returns>The ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler bound to this property</returns>
        public static ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler GetViewModelTerminatingEvent
        (DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (dependencyObject.GetValue(ViewModelTerminatingEventProperty)
                as ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the ViewModelTerminatingEvent dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetViewModelTerminatingEvent(
            DependencyObject dependencyObject,
            ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler value)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(ViewModelTerminatingEventProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the ViewModelTerminatingEvent dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void ViewModelTerminatingEventPropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject d, 
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window instance = d as Window;
            if (null != instance)
            {
                if (null != e.OldValue)
                {
                    throw new System.InvalidOperationException(
                    "ViewModelTerminatingEvent dependency property cannot be changed.");
                }

                if (null != e.NewValue)
                {
                    // Attach the Window.Close() method to the ViewModel's event
                    var newEvent = (e.NewValue as ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler);
                    newEvent += new ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler(() => instance.Close());
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Source for MainWindow.xaml:
(This example contains code-behind to simplify the Stop Button implementation.)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfEventBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:WpfEventBinding"
        v:WindowBindableProperties.ViewModelTerminatingEvent="{Binding Path=RequestCloseEvent}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=CloseCommandName}" Click="StopButton_Click" ></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Source for MainWindow.xaml.cs (code behind):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfEventBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindowViewModel vm = (DataContext as MainWindowViewModel);
            if (null != vm)
            {
                vm.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source for the MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfEventBinding
{
    public delegate void ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler();

    class MainWindowViewModel
        : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Raised by the ViewModel to indicate to the view that it is no longer required.
        // Causes System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error.  Is it
        // Possible to bind to an 'event' property?
        public event ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler RequestCloseEvent;

        // This has to have the public 'get' to allow binding.  Is there some way to
        // do the same thing for the 'event'?
        public String CloseCommandName { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            CloseCommandName = "Close";
        }

        internal void Stop()
        {
            ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler RaiseRequestCloseEvent =
                RequestCloseEvent;
            if (null != RaiseRequestCloseEvent)
            {
                RaiseRequestCloseEvent();
            }
        }

        internal void Start()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("CloseCommandName");
            OnPropertyChanged("ViewModelTerminatingEvent");
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler RaisePropertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;
            if (RaisePropertyChangedEvent != null)
            {
                var propertyChangedEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source for App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfEventBinding.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Nothing to see here.  Move along... -->
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Source for App.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfEventBinding
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Startup += new StartupEventHandler(App_Startup);
        }

        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

            // Make sure this is set before attempting binding!
            window.DataContext = vm;
            vm.Start();
            window.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that the `public event ViewModelTerminatingEventHandler RequestCloseEvent;` syntax is not sufficient to allo the data binding to occur.  A similar problem is see if the `public String CloseCommandName { get; private set; }` is declared as `public String CloseCommandName;` without the `{ get; private set; }`.  However, there is no `{ get; private set; }` for events, which use the `{add{} remove{}}` syntax (and that does not solve the problem either).

Is what I'm attempting possible and if so, what have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View closing means window closing event. So you basically want react on events in the view. I read recently this [arcticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx), there was a very good image

[image]

and also mentioned `EventBehavior` existence.

Your best bet, if you don't want any code behind, is to use behaviors. Behavior is a simple attached property, which can perform actions, to example rising application-wide commands, which `ViewModel` can then catch without `MVVM` issues.

Here is an example of behavior:

```
public static class FreezeBehavior
{
    public static bool GetIsFrozen(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFrozenProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsFrozen(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFrozenProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFrozenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFrozen", typeof(bool), typeof(FreezeBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnIsFrozenChanged));

    private static void OnIsFrozenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            var freezable = d as Freezable;
            if (freezable != null && freezable.CanFreeze)
                freezable.Freeze();
        }
    }
}
```

it's used like this

```
<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" local:FreezeBehavior.IsFrozen="True"/>
```

It can be attached to any freezable to freeze it. In your case you want to subscribe to event and invoke command or set property, or whatever to inform `ViewModel`.

Comment: Yes!  All I need to do is change it's type to a `Boolean` and `PropertyChanged` event is already part of the framework.  FYI: my application has another DependencyProperty that allows the ViewModel to subscribe to the Closed event from the Window, this is a mechanism that allows the ViewModel to indicate to the view that the Window is no longer required and can be closed.

Comment: ... This method even allows my ViewModel to expose another ViewModel property that represents a DataContext for a new View that it wants displayed. Epiphany! I'd double up-vote if I could.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is kinda weird, but I'm not going to get into a big long discussion about that....

You don't bind to events - you expose them and the view can add handlers for the events.

Of course this means you will have to put some code behind into the view - but this is fine provided it is UI related. To complete the decoupling your view should only handle the viewmodel as an interface, this means you can easily swap out viewmodels at a later stage.

(Note that I've avoided talking about [event triggers](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/)).

Comment: My application does use an interface, which can expose an event.  The interface has been removed here to simplify the example.  I'll look into event triggers.  I'm starting to think that my 'NoCodeBehindWindow' base class needs to grow and incorporate a little more (not quite) code-behind to avoid real code-behind in the xaml objects that instantiate it.